# How toggle (invert) databound ListBox SelectedItems in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

Can loop through selected items using "SelectedItems.Count" & "SelectedItems(i)".
Can loop through all items using "Items.Count" & "Items(i)".
How best reverse IsSelected of each Items(i) when IsSelected property is not available?

(Note: Becuase ListBox is data-templated and data-bound, each Items(i) is a DataRowView and not a ListBoxItem.)

Comment: Don't use `System.Data` in WPF client-side. Create a proper DataModel instead. Also, I suggest creating a reusable `Selectable<T>` class with a `public bool IsSelected {get;set;}` property that you can bind `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`,etc. against.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through all items:

```
Foreach(ListBoxItem Item in CustomerListBox.Items)
(
    Item.Selected = IIf(Item.Selected, false, true)
)
```

Comment: -1. The OP just said that `Items` contains `DataRowVies` and not `ListBoxItems`. Your code will cause a runtime `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: @HighCore - that being the case, there's another layer in this that the OP didn't mention.  DataGridViewRows don't have checkboxes, they have cells.  One of the cells could be a checkbox.  I would need to know the name of the cell.

Comment: my appreciation still stands. `System.Data` stuff sucks. magic strings everywhere.

Comment: SelectedItems & Items are built into wpf ListBoxes, so are SelectAll & SelectedItems.Clear. Is there an InvertSelection method hidden somewhere?

Comment: @Guppy - no. The above code simply iterates through the list of items changing the Selected status.  If a method existed, it wouldn't be hidden.

Comment: Using SelectedItems.Add to (re)build the Selection can be extremely slow, yet SelectAll is rapid irrespective of List size. This suggests the internal workings have access the public methods and properties do not. (I remember using a BingMaps hack where functionality was missing.)